# Spring Integration: copy one inbound message to multiple outbound

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, mqtt

I want to use Spring Integration to process MQTT messages.

This is my processing requirements: based on inbound message payload it should be copied to multiple messages with same payload but different headers. More specifically different MQTT topic header since I want to send them to different topics.

Also outbound messages should be sent in order: at first all transformed messages from the 1st inbound message, then all messages from the 2nd inbound messages etc.

What message endpoint(s) should I use to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, what you're describing is actually not MQTT specific, rather an enterprise integration pattern called [splitter](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/Sequencer.html) and Spring Integration provides support for it which you can configure using XML, Annotation and/or Java DSL. You can find more info [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#splitter).

In a nut shell Splitter is a Message Handler with a specific contract allowing it to return "many" from a "single" (kind of the reverse of aggregator). You basically receive a message (from MQTT in your case) and split it on multiple messages inside your splitter implementation.

Comment: Thanks! And what is the way to implement ordering? If I am not mistaken Resequencer re-orders messages inside one group of splitted messages only. But I want to send through outbound adapter all splitted messages from 1st inbound message before any splitted messages from 2nd inbound message etc. While still be able to process messages in parallel, for example with ExecutorChannel.

Comment: As long as everything is on the single thread (which by default it will be), there is no  issue with ordering since the list contract will be maintained - FIFO. So you don't need resequencer at the moment. If however you do break the thread boundaries then we can talk about how you can benefit from resequencer.